# Silverlight app as a service provider

Tags: c#, java, silverlight, web-services

I'm googling for a tutorial or an introduction how to make a silverlight application a service provider. Here is the deal:

Java app sends a SOAP message to a Silverlight control

```
 Soap stuff..
  <ShowVisualisation>
    <URL>http://www.example.org/simulations/sim1.txt</URL>
  </ShowVisualisation>
 Soap stuff..
```

when SL app gets the message, it needs to download this text file and process it. Writing WSDL on you own is really tedious and error prone.

Is there a tutorial/example how to build a SL service that is .Net independent? I'm looking for some WSDL generation.

EDIT:

I got through the articles and it seems there is no easy way to make SL app a service provider. SL app won't be hosted on IIS. Hence, the message is very simple, is there any better way to communicate?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use WCF RIA here is a link to get you started

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services

I do not believe you will be able to host your web service within your silverlight project but within the same solution. This might a bit more complexity than expected to have this ultra responsive. The good thing is that you should not have to handle any WSDL stuff visual studio and eclipse will take of this for you.

Cheers,

Comment: Are you sure? "A Silverlight client is not addressable over HTTP because the browser environment does not allow the creation of an HTTP listener. HTTP duplex communication with a Silverlight client is achieved by having the client poll a destination server for messages from within an established session." Seems I have too pool ;/

Comment: Maybe we have small misunderstanding, the wcf services will be created in a separate project but within the same solution. You could even create them in the ASP.NET project that is hosting your Silverlight XAP object. Then once deployed on IIS you will be able from silverlight to use those WCF services. Hopefully it makes a bit more sense. But you are right from within silverlight you will not be able to host any http services.

Comment: I have never actually tried this but look at the section "Hosting a Service in an Arbitrary Process" I don't know how much of help this can be but might be worth reading to see if you could apply this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee958158.aspx